# What does Device Extension means

Tags: driver

PDEVICE_EXTENSION is a Structure.
And fdo is device structure object.

```
PDEVICE_EXTENSION pdx = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION) fdo->DeviceExtension;
```

What Does it mean about the following code?

Answer (score 1):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx --

> **Device Extensions**
>
> For most intermediate and lowest-level drivers, the device extension
> is the most important data structure associated with a device object.
> Its internal structure is driver-defined, and it is typically used to:
>
> - Maintain device state information.
> - Provide storage for any
>   kernel-defined objects or other system resources, such as spin locks,
>   used by the driver.
> - Hold any data the driver must have resident and in
>   system space to carry out its I/O operations.
>
> ...